# Proper Netplan configuration for dual nic dhcp/static IP setup

Tags: netplan

I am having trouble getting a good mental map of how to configure netplan for a common network setup we are seeing.

1. Two network interfaces
2. Network interface A, connected to the internet on 10.0.1.40/24, assigned via DHCP
3. Network interface B, connected to a network on 192.168.50.1/24 via 192.168.50.1/24 assigned a static IP (192.168.50.20/24)

Something like:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp6s0f1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.50.20/24
      gateway4: 192.168.50.1
```

Seems like it should work, but after applying this, it seems that either

1. The server loses internet access and somehow the static IP address has a lower priority than the dhcp interface? Is that possible?
2. The server *has* network access, but cannot communicate with any of the devices on the `192.168.50.1/24` network (possibly using the wrong ethernet card).

FWIW, removing the non-dhcp interface from netplan and just using `sudo ip addr add 192.168.50.20/24 dev eno2` "just works", however doesn't persist across reboots.

The final route table looks like this:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.50.1 dev enp6s0f1 proto dhcp src 192.168.50.11 metric 100 
default via 10.1.10.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 10.1.10.178 metric 100 
10.1.10.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.10.178 
10.1.10.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.10.178 metric 100 
192.168.50.0/24 dev enp6s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.11 
192.168.50.1 dev enp6s0f1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.50.11 metric 100
```

In this case, the `192.168.50.1` is the static network that does not have public internet access, but the `10.1.10.1` route is not used.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `ip route` when using this Netplan configuration that you’re having a problem with?

Comment: The output of `ip route` has been added.

Comment: The interfaces and IP addresses in the output of `ip route` aren't matching with what you've described. You're configuring `eno1` and `eno2` yet `ip route` is showing `eno1` and `enp6s0f1`. Could you please edit question to include the output of `ip a` and `lshw -C network`?

Comment: I've updated the question match the results of the test setup I had to deliver the results I've shown. Conceptually the problem is still the same - it looks like netplan assigns a default route to the secondary network and it isn't clear how to disable that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have your Netplan YAML file configured now, you have two default routes setup. The output of `ip route` indicates that. The first default route on `eno1` is given to you from the DHCP server. The other on `enp6s0f1` is being defined in your YAML file. Furthermore, each default route has a metric of 100, so one default route isn't getting a priority over the other.

You have two options...either assign a different metric for `eno1` so that it takes priority over `enp6s0f1`, or remove the `gateway4` stanza for `enp6s0f1`. Since you indicate that all internet traffic should go out `eno1` and `enp6s0f1` is strictly for the `192.168.50.0/24` subnet, just remove the `gateway4` stanza as follows:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp6s0f1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.50.20/24
```